# Find a 4x4 matrix A (non-zero entries only) with 3 eigenvectors coming from a single eigenvalue of your choice.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Since the single eigenvalue contributes to 3 eigenvectors, I interpret the question to be that there is a repeated root for the characteristic equation.

I thought about forming the characteristic equation using a repeated root. For example, I can choose an arbitrary eigenvalue, λ=3 to be the single eigenvalue forming 3 eigenvectors. I then form (λ-3)^3(λ-1)=0 and expand it, but I'm unsure if this is the right way?

However, I am unsure as to how I should go about/start forming the matrix. How do I approach this question?

Edit:

Referencing @hardmath's comment, I realised that repeated roots can indeed lead to linearly dependent eigenvectors. Hence, I came up with a diagonal matrix A with 3 columns sharing the same eigenvalue 1, while the last one has the eigenvalue 4.

*My current matrix is a diagonal matrix, so I can identify the eigenvalue easily by looking at the values on the main diagonal. I'm not sure how to form the matrix if it is not a triangular matrix.

A= \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&4\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Please say what you have tried. Just uploading a problem is not the right way.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Hi, I was only able to interpret the question as mentioned but I'm not quite sure how to begin. Would appreciate any pointers at all, thank you!

Comment: Start with a choice of your eigenvalue and use the definition of eigenvectors.

Comment: I suggest working out a solution without the restriction on nonzero entries.  That could then be modified by a similarity transformation to get all nonzero entries. Repeated roots of the characteristic equation don't always imply a full set of linearly independent eigenvalues.

Comment: @hardmath Hi, sorry I'm not really sure what "without the restriction on nonzero entries" refer to. I added an edit, does it correspond to what you suggested?

Comment: I was suggesting a way you could do work toward a solution, getting a better sense of what the problem is about. I see your edit indicates more insight.

Comment: The most straightforward matrix with all entries $\ne0$ is the matrix mith all entries $=1$.

Comment: Welcome to the 21th century. We have something called "internet" and it looks like you're not familiar with it, since you don't know that writing in ALL CAPS is the equivalent of shouting and is not considered polite.

Comment: @jjagmath tell that to my prof who typed that question! haha ok but i'm sorry, i edited the title :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is correct when taking the diagonal form of your matrix $A$. Since your matrix should have 3 eigenvectors coming from the same eigenvalue $\lambda$, then

$$3=\gamma_\lambda\leq\mu_\lambda\leq 4,$$

where $\gamma$ and $\mu$ correspond to the geometric and algebraic multiplicities of your eigenvalue. So, either all the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda$ or there is another eigenvalue $\lambda'$.

Taking the latter to be the case (if not, your matrix is just a scalar multiple of the identity whose eigenvectors are the canonical vectors) then the diagonal form of $A$ should look like

$$D=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda&0&0&0\\0&\lambda&0&0\\0&0&\lambda&0\\0&0&0&\lambda'\\\end{pmatrix}$$

To construct $A$ choose any vector $\vec v_1\in\mathbb R^4$. Then choose $\vec v_2$ in any way such that $\vec v_2\neq c\vec v_1$ for $c\in\mathbb R$. The kernel of the matrix whose rows are $\vec v_1$ and $\vec v_2$ shall give you a 2 dimensional space where you can find a linearly independent $\vec v_3,\ \vec v_4$ which you can assign to the last vectors. These vectors will form the change-of-basis matrix from the canonical basis to the the basis $\{\vec v_1,\dots,\vec v_4\}$. Multiplying $D$ on both sides by this matrix and its inverse will give us $A$

As an example take for your first vector $\vec v_1= (1,1,0,0)$. A linearly independent vector from that could be $\vec v_2 =(1,0,1,1)$. Then the matrix $B$ whose rows are these vectors has a null space generated by $\vec v_3=(-1,1,1,0)$ and $\vec v_4 = (-1,1,0,1)$. Then

$$P=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&-1&-1\\1&0&1&1\\0&1&1&0\\0&1&0&1\\\end{pmatrix}\Rightarrow P^{-1}=\frac15\begin{pmatrix}2&3&-1&-1\\1&-1&2&2\\-1&1&3&-2\\-1&1&-2&3\end{pmatrix}.$$

Thus, taking $\lambda=1,\ \lambda'=4$ we get

$$A=PDP^{-1}=\frac15\begin{pmatrix}8&-3&6&-9\\-3&8&-6&9\\0&0&5&0\\-3&3&-6&14\end{pmatrix}.$$

This matrix $A$ has as a diagonal form the matrix $D$ which has three eigenvectors associated to $\lambda=1$ and one associated to $\lambda=4$.

Let me know if this helps!